# F# Testing for Base Types With Pattern Matching and Boxing of Tuples

Tags: f#, boxing, type-testing

I try to understand the concept of boxing and testing for base types, especially with tuples.

I have two objects from an external C# library that have different concrete types but share a common base type:

```ml
let o1 = ConcreteType1() // has base type BaseType
let o2 = ConcreteType2() // also has base type BaseType
```

If both `o1` and `o2` are derived from `BaseType`, I have to perform some special comparison logic, so I'd like to test whether the elements of a tuple `(o1, o2)` both have base type `BaseType`.

Based on the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214274/f-pattern-matching-on-types-of-tuples), I gather that I have to box *each element* of the type *separately* and perform the type tests on the individual elements, so that base types are considered:

```ml
match box o1, box o2 with
| (:? BaseType), (:? BaseType) -> // special logic with o1, o2
| _ -> // nope, some other behavior
```

My understanding is that simply boxing the tuple itself will not upcast the individual elements to `obj`, and the test for their base types will therefore not work:

```ml
match box (o1, o2) with
| :? (BaseType * BaseType) -> // never hit, because elements are not upcast to obj
| _ -> // ...
```

Is this the correct explanation for the observed behavior, or are there other mechanisms involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that boxing a tuple doesn't box the tuple's items. However, even if you manually boxed the items as well, it still wouldn't match. So the following code prints `"Unknown"`:

```ml
match box (box o1, box o2) with
    | :? (BaseType * BaseType) -> printfn "BaseType"
    | _ -> printfn "Unknown"   // hit
```

This is because `ConcreteType1 * ConcreteType2` is *not* a subtype of either `BaseType * BaseType` or `obj * obj`. Note that the following code won't even compile:

```ml
let testBad (tuple : BaseType * BaseType) =
    tuple :?> (ConcreteType1 * ConcreteType2)   // compiler error: can't cast
```

That means the following code will print `"ConcreteType"`:

```ml
match box (o1, o2) with
    | :? (BaseType * BaseType) -> printfn "BaseType"
    | :? (ConcreteType1 * ConcreteType2) -> printfn "ConcreteType"   // hit
    | _ -> printfn "Unknown"
```

This is just the way that polymorphic types interact with OO subtyping. As another example, `List<ConcreteType1>` isn't a subtype of `List<BaseType>`, so no amount of boxing and casting will get them to match either.

The confusing thing is that F# does have a special case where it will automatically cast a `ConcreteType1 * ConcreteType2` argument to match a `BaseType * BaseType` parameter:

```ml
let testGood (tuple : BaseType * BaseType) =
    printfn "good"

testGood (o1, o2)   // this works and prints "good"
```

I think this is because tupled arguments are common in other languages, so F# is trying to maintain compatibility, but I'm not certain.